# sudo apt-get update doesn't work on Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: apt, updatedb

I am trying to update my Linux Mint 17.1.

But if I give this commands,

`sudo apt-get update`

it is giving the following error.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

As quoted in the errors, the `lock` file is looking like the following,

[image]
How I can use this commands??

### Update:

After the comments given by, I closed my synaptic package manager and tried but it gave the following

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for biostat: 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy InRelease                                   

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release.gpg                                 
  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://liveusb.info all InRelease                                          

Err http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      

Err http://liveusb.info all Release.gpg                                        
  Unable to connect to liveusb.info:http:
Err http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:1450:400d:807::200e 80]
Err http://www.remastersys.com quantal InRelease                               

Err http://www.remastersys.com quantal Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to www.remastersys.com:http:
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              

Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                            
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b 80]
Err http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca InRelease                            

Err http://packages.linuxmint.com rebecca Release.gpg                          
  Unable to connect to packages.linuxmint.com:http: [IP: 68.235.39.11 80]
Err http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca InRelease                               

Err http://extra.linuxmint.com rebecca Release.gpg                             
  Unable to connect to extra.linuxmint.com:http: [IP: 68.235.39.11 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                       

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg                     
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease       

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg     
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/dists/all/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extra.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/saucy/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/aims/sagemath/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://liveusb.info/multisystem/depot/dists/all/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to liveusb.info:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2a00:1450:400d:807::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2a00:1450:400d:807::200e 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to www.remastersys.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.canonical.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::1b 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to packages.linuxmint.com:http: [IP: 68.235.39.11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://extra.linuxmint.com/dists/rebecca/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to extra.linuxmint.com:http: [IP: 68.235.39.11 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1562::15 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8c01::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
biostat@biostat-HP-Compaq-dc5750-Microtower ~ $
```

Comment: Same issue after a reboot?

Comment: reboot?? should i have to reboot???but nothing i have done know??@RubanSavvy

Comment: Kill the shown processes `pgrep dpkg`

Comment: kindly give procedure.. i am somewhat for these workings..@A.B.

Comment: Now it looks like a network problem, not necessarily an APT problem.

Comment: Are you using a proxy to connect to the internet?

Comment: yes..its my department internet..so we are using manual proxy@Wilf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close Synaptic package manager and try again.

Comment: you are right..after closing synaptic package manager it ran..but so many "unable to connect" messages are coming...

Comment: Can you update your question by addition of those "unable to connect" messages?

Comment: i have updated my question @siblynx